# Do antipsychotics have a delayed onset of action similar to (monoamine) antidepressants?

Tags: neuroscience, abnormal-psychology, psychopharmacology, psychosis

I've been trying to understand the position of [Steve Hyman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Hyman) (a former NIMH director), who has been amply quoted in [an recent article in Quartz](https://qz.com/1162154/30-years-after-prozac-arrived-we-still-buy-the-lie-that-chemical-imbalances-cause-depression/), saying among ohter things that

> There’s not “an iota of direct evidence” for the theory that a chemical imbalance causes depression.

I looked into Hyman's papers and I found a fairly cited (~500 in Google Scholar) [paper of his some 20 years ago in AJP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8561194), co-authored with [Eric J. Nestler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_J._Nestler), in which they propose that

> drug-induced neural plasticity [...] underlies the long-term actions of psychotropic drugs in the brain [...] Biological investigation in psychiatry has often focused too narrowly on synaptic pharmacology,
>   especially on neurotransmitter turnover and neurotransmitter receptors. A paradigm is presented to help understand the long-term effects of psychotropic drugs, including
>   the latency in onset of their therapeutic actions.

The paper further details that

> Acute dosing of the antidepressants
>   produces little in the way of subjective or
>   behavioral effects (other than side effects). Initial doses
>   of the antipsychotic drugs produce subtle motor effects
>   or some degree of sedation, and initial doses of the
>   stimulants produce euphoria and locomotor activation.
>   However, substantial improvement in depressive or
>   psychotic symptoms, or the development of addiction
>   to psychostimulant drugs, occurs only if the drugs are
>   taken at adequate dosage and with adequate frequency
>   and chronicity. For example, depressive symptoms
>   would not be expected to improve if an antidepressant
>   were taken at too low a dose, only occasionally, or for
>   too short a period of time.
>
> We therefore conceptualize antidepressant-induced
>   increases in synaptic serotonin or norepinephrine, antipsychotic-
>   induced blockade of dopamine neurotransmission,
>   and cocaine- and amphetamine-induced increases
>   in synaptic dopamine as initiating events for longerterm
>   changes in neural function. It is the adaptive response
>   of the nervous system to adequate repeated perturbations
>   mediated through these initial targets that
>   produces the therapeutic responses to antidepressants
>   or antipsychotic drugs or, in the case of the psychostimulants,
>   addiction [...].

I'm somewhat familiar with the [slow, cumulative effect of monoamine antidepressants](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2211759/figure/F2/) and with the mechanism of addiction. Hyman and Nestler can be probably be forgiven for not anticipating the [ketamine-as-fast-antidepressant fervor](http://time.com/magazine/us/4876068/august-7th-2017-vol-190-no-6-u-s/) 20 years later. But what I want to ask here is:

**What is the evidence that anti-psychotics also work in this delayed manner? Is it uncontroversially so?**

Comment: typical or atypical antipsychotics?

Comment: @faustus: they don't particularize their statements to one sub-class of antipsychotics anywhere in the paper, as far as I can tell.

Comment: are you interested in the first quote, or the answer.re: antipsychotics mechanism of action? the quote is a broader statement about biological psychiatry. it's a position that i share, though i accept that it's not a conventional one.

Comment: @faustus: not in this question. It's just for context how I got to read the Hyman and Nestler position paper. The "chemical imbalance" has been derided by other professionals in the field as a [silly, dumbed down version](http://www.psychiatrictimes.com/blogs/nuances-narratives-chemical-imbalance-debate) of the various monoamine hypotheses proposed by researchers. I was trying to understand in exactly what way Hyman rejects that "chemical imbalance". Once a straw man is set up, there are many ways to burn it down...

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be multiple studies generally pointing to a delay of clinical antipsychotic action of these drugs, typically between a week and two weeks (*e.g.*., [Zedkova *et al* (2011)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22167144) and [Mousavi *et al*. (2013)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4076925/)). However, there is evidence that antipsychotics may start working after a day, or even within a few hours after starting the meds. See for an interesting review [Agid *et al*. (2006)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1413955/).

From reading these papers my understanding is that a lot of it depends on where the researcher puts the threshold of ***[clinical effectiveness](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/aboutcer/)*** and which outcome measure is used to define that effectiveness.

<sub>**References**

**-** [Agid *et al*., *J Psychiatry Neurosci* (2006); **31**(2): 93–100](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1413955/)

**-** [Mousavi *et al*., *J Res Pharm Pract* (2013); **2**(4): 138–44](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4076925/)

**-** [Zedkova *et al*., *Neuro Endocrinol Lett* (2011); **32**(5): 667-70](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22167144)</sub>